# Can't resolve 'semantic-ui-react'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I think I followed all steps for set up 'semantic-ui-react' that other said to do but there is an error.

> ERROR in
>   ./assets/components/UserPage/UserPageQuestion/UserPageQuestion.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'semantic-ui-react' in
>   'C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\assets\components\UserPage\UserPageQuestion'
>   @ ./assets/components/UserPage/UserPageQuestion/UserPageQuestion.js
>   31:0-67 91:63-70 91:98-104 93:29-35 93:76-81 95:31-38 95:66-72
>   98:29-35 100:42-47  @ ./assets/components/UserPage/index.js  @
>   ./assets/components/UserPage/UserPage.js  @ multi
>   ./assets/components/UserPage/UserPage.js

**package.json**

```
...

"dependencies": {
    ...
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.3.3",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.82.4",
    ...
  }

...
```

**UserPageQuestion.js**

```
import { Dimmer, Loader, Image, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'

import '../../../../../static/cebula/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.min.js';
import '../../../../../static/cebula/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.min.css';

const UserPageQuestion = () => {
     return (
          <Segment>
                 <Dimmer active>
                       <Loader>Loading</Loader>
                 </Dimmer>
                 <Image src='/images/wireframe/short-paragraph.png' />
          </Segment>
     )

}
```

What's the problem??

Comment: why have you imported semantic.min.* ?

Answer (score 5):

In your `UserPageQuestion.js` remove the following 2 `imports`:

```
import '../../../../../static/cebula/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.min.js';
import '../../../../../static/cebula/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.min.css';
```

Just include the minified CSS file in your ***index.js*** file:

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
```

Source: [Semantic UI docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage#semantic-ui-css-package)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to solve your problem:

```
export default UserPageQuestion
```